# How to wget info into Postgresql database and create a table for it?

Tags: sql, ddl, postgresql-9.5

I am currently working on a side project for myself so I can learn how to use postgresql and read database logs. The goal of the project is to create a database that is checking a website for a key word and the database will log how many times that word was found or not found from the website. Every time the word is found there will be a timestamp added to tell me at what time and the date of when the word was found.

So far I have created my database but I am stuck in creating table and I do not know how to wget the information into the table. I am building this postgresql on ubuntu linux system.

Comment: [Creating a New Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-table.html) in the Postgres tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Create the table with SQL.

In Postgres 10 and some other databases that would be:

```
CREATE TABLE word_found_ (
    id_    BIGINT                         -- 64-bit number for virtually unlimited number of records.
           GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY   -- Generate sequential number by default. Tag as NOT NULL.
           PRIMARY KEY ,                  -- Create index to enforce UNIQUE.
    when_  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.      -- Store the moment adjusted into UTC.
           DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,    -- Get the moment when this current transaction began.
    count_ INTEGER                        -- The number of times the target word was found.
) ;
```

Before Postgres 10, use `SERIAL` instead of `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`. Alternatively, search Stack Overflow for info about using UUID as primary key with values generated by default by ossp-uuid extension.

Insert a row for each sample you take.

```
INSERT INTO  word_found_ ( count_ )
VALUES ( 42 ) 
;
```